# Python - Shuffle then extend list

Tags: python

I have a program that takes three values from the user, minimum, maximum, and sets. The program then shuffles the range of values between the minimum and maximum and prints each value on an individual line. For example, if the user enters 1 and 5, the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 are shuffled and each number is printed on its own line. I want to repeat this process the number of times the user specifies by the 'sets' value. If 'sets' = 2, I want to shuffle the first set (e.g., 1, 5, 3, 2, 4), shuffle the second set (3, 2, 1, 5, 4), extend the second set to the first set (e.g., 1, 5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4), then print each number on its own line. The code below works for generating one set of values, but no matter what the 'sets' value is, only one set of values is generated.

```
import random
a = 1
b = 5
c = 2
d = []
x = 0
e = list(range(a, b+1))
while x < c:
    random.shuffle(e)
    for i in e:
        print(e[x])
        d.extend([e])
        x+=1
```

Comment: It's indirectly relevant - values in the relevant portion of code are pulled from keys for user input in the GUI

Comment: Edited per your recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

`random.shuffle()` shuffles the list in place. This mean the function doesn't return anything, which makes it a little less convenient that just using `random.sample()`. The docs say this:

> To shuffle an immutable sequence and return a new shuffled list, use sample(x, k=len(x)) instead.

So to make a list of concatenated shuffles you could do:

```
from random import sample

e = list(range(1, 6))
num = 2

numbers = [n for _ in range(num) for n in sample(e, k=len(e))]
# [1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4] (or similar)
```

This isn't *technically* reshuffling the shuffled list, but if the process is even close to random the results should be indistinguishable.